# Django: complex Formset validation, self.instance value makes no sense

Tags: django, validation, formset, inline-formset

I'm trying to overwrite the clean method on a formset. As the documentation proposes, I wrote my own BaseFormSet and overrode it's clean method. Some of the values of the FormSet depend on values from the parenting model form.

The model is an Entry in an application that holds working time. An Entry applies to a day and there can only be one Entry, however an Entry can have several Shifts. As you can imagine, the model form is for the Entry, the FormSet is for the Shifts. So the Entry is the parent, the Shifts are the children.

In order to validate a Shift, I need to access the parent Entry. I tried to do so by calling self.instance from within the clean method. self in this case would be the FormSet.

However, the content of self.instance is always an Entry for the current day, that is lacking it's owner. If I'm trying to add an Entry for the 4th of January, self.instance should be for that date. However, when I access self.instance, the result is an entry for today. However the form for the Entry is valid. All values are entered correctly. There should be an owner.

My question is, am I using self.instance correctly? And if not, how can I access the values of the parent Entry from the Shift FormSet during validation?

Definition of Shift:

```
class Shift(m.Model):
    TIME_HELP_TEXT = 'Please use the following format: <em>HH:MM</em>.'
    # meta
    cr_date = m.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Date of Creation')  # date of creation
    # content
    entry   = m.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=m.CASCADE, related_name='shifts')
    start   = m.TimeField(help_text=TIME_HELP_TEXT)  # starting time
    end     = m.TimeField(help_text=TIME_HELP_TEXT)  # ending time
    recess  = m.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)  # recess time in minutes
    project = m.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=m.PROTECT)
```

Definition of Entry:

```
class Entry(m.Model):
    """ Represents an entry in a accounting. An entry is either for work, sick leave or VACATION. """
    # meta
    cr_date = m.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name='Date of Creation')  # date of creation
    owner   = m.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=m.PROTECT, unique_for_date='date')
    final   = m.BooleanField(default=False)
    # content
    type    = m.CharField(max_length=1, choices=type_choices, default='w')
    date    = m.DateField(default=now)
```

FormSet Declaration:

```
class BaseShiftFormSet(f.BaseInlineFormSet):
    warnings = []

    def has_messages(self):
        return self.warnings

    def flush_messages(self, request):
        for w in self.warnings:
            messages.warning(request, w)

    def clean(self):
        if any(self.errors):
            # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own.
            return

        super(BaseShiftFormSet, self).clean()

        # Standard day. Is used to be combined with Time object instances in order to get Datetime object instances,
        # which allow for arithmetic comparison as opposed to Time objects.
        # entry = self.instance
        # day = datetime.date(entry.get_year(), entry.get_month(), entry.get_day())
        day = datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
        one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        # previous_entry = Entry.get_entry_for_day(entry.get_owner(), day - one_day)
        # next_entry = Entry.get_entry_for_day(entry.get_owner(), day + one_day)
        earliest = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.time(hour=6))
        latest = datetime.datetime.combine(day, datetime.time(hour=20))
        # shifts = entry.get_shifts()
        valid = True
        work_time = datetime.timedelta()
        work_time_limit = datetime.timedelta(hours=10)
        min_break = datetime.timedelta(hours=11)

        for form in self.forms:
            start        = datetime.datetime.combine(day, form.cleaned_data['start'])
            end          = datetime.datetime.combine(day, form.cleaned_data['end'])
            recess_time  = datetime.timedelta(minutes=form.cleaned_data['recess'])
            shift_length = end - start
            # new_shift    = Shift(start=form.cleaned_data['start'], end=form.cleaned_data['end'],
            #                      recess=form.cleaned_data['recess'], project=form.cleaned_data['project'],
            #                      entry=entry)
            work_time   += shift_length - recess_time

            # Validation: LOGICAL ERRORS
            # Start before end.
            if start > end:
                raise ValidationError(ERROR_MESSAGES['shift_inconsistent'])
            # Recess not longer than total work time.
            if recess_time >= shift_length:
                raise ValidationError(ERROR_MESSAGES['shift_recess_too_long'])
            # # No overlapping shifts
            # for shift in shifts:
            #     valid = valid and (new_shift.is_before(shift) or new_shift.is_after(shift))
            # if not valid:
            #     raise ValidationError(ERROR_MESSAGES['shifts_overlap'])

        #     # Validation: WARNINGS
        #     # No night shifts. Applies only to office work.
        #     if entry.is_type_work():
        #         # Avoid starting before 6:00.
        #         if start < earliest:
        #             self.warnings.append(WARNING_MESSAGES['no_night_shifts'])
        #         # Avoid starting after 22:00.
        #         if end > latest:
        #             self.warnings.append(WARNING_MESSAGES['no_night_shifts'])
        #
        # # No shifts longer than ten hours
        # if work_time >= work_time_limit:
        #     self.warnings.append(WARNING_MESSAGES['shift_too_long'])
        #
        # # Minimum break of 11 hours between work days.
        # gap = entry.calculate_time_gap(previous_entry)
        # if gap:
        #     if gap < min_break:
        #         self.warnings.append(WARNING_MESSAGES['no_11_hour_break'].
        #                              format(previous_entry.get_date().strftime('%d %m %Y')))
        # gap = entry.calculate_time_gap(next_entry)
        # if gap:
        #     if gap < min_break:
        #         self.warnings.append(WARNING_MESSAGES['no_11_hour_break'].
        #                              format(next_entry.get_date().strftime('%d %m %Y')))


fields = ('entry', 'project', 'start', 'end', 'recess', )
CreateShiftFormSet = f.inlineformset_factory(Entry, Shift, formset=BaseShiftFormSet, fields=fields, extra=0,
                                             can_delete=False, min_num=1, validate_min=True)
EditShiftFormSet = f.inlineformset_factory(Entry, Shift, formset=BaseShiftFormSet, fields=fields, extra=1,
                                           can_delete=True, min_num=1, validate_min=True)
```

The Views in which the above elements are used:

```
class EntryView(FormView):
    """ Base view. """
    model = Entry
    form_class = f.EntryForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('time_manager:time_tracking:index')
    formset = CreateShiftFormSet
    object = None

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Fallback url.
        url = reverse('time_manager:time_tracking:index')
        # If possible, go back to the month were the last entry was added.
        if self.object:
            url = reverse('time_manager:time_tracking:month',
                          kwargs={'year': self.object.get_year(), 'month': self.object.get_month()})
        return url

    def get(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if pk:
            try:
                self.object = Entry.objects.get(pk=pk)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                self.object = None
        else:
            self.object = None

        if self.object:
            form = f.EntryForm(instance=self.object)
            form_set = self.formset(instance=self.object)
        else:
            form = f.EntryForm(initial={'owner': request.user})
            form_set = self.formset()

        return_dict = {'form': form, 'shift_form': form_set}

        return render(request, self.template_name, return_dict)

    def post(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if pk:
            self.object = Entry.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            self.object = None

        if self.object:
            form = f.EntryForm(data=request.POST, instance=self.object)
            shift_form_set = self.formset(data=request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            form = f.EntryForm(data=request.POST)
            shift_form_set = self.formset(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and shift_form_set.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(request.user, form, shift_form_set)
        else:
            rd = {'form': form, 'shift_form': shift_form_set, 'test': self.object}

            return render(request, self.template_name, rd)

    def form_valid(self, user, form, shift_form):
        """ Stores the entry and all shifts. """
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner = user
        self.object.save()
        shift_form.instance = self.object
        shifts = shift_form.save(commit=False)
        for shift in shifts:
            shift.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


class EntryCreateView(EntryView):
    """ View for creating new entries. Can be passed an ordinal to create an entry for the day, represented by the
        ordinal. """
    template_name = 'entry/create.html'
    form_class = f.AddWorkDay

    def get(self, request, ordinal=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Initiates with a blank form or will populate the day field with the day represented by the passed
            ordinal. """
        if ordinal:
            date = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(int(ordinal))
            form = f.AddWorkDay(initial={'date': date, 'owner': request.user})
        else:
            form = f.AddWorkDay(initial={'owner': request.user})
        shift_form_set = CreateShiftFormSet(instance=self.object)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'shift_form': shift_form_set})


class EntryEditView(EntryView):
    template_name = 'entry/edit.html'
    formset = EditShiftFormSet
```

Comment: In an inline formset, `instance` is the "parent" object that all the inlines relate to.

Comment: I know, but when I call self.instance, the values make no sense. I'm trying to add an Entry for the 4th of January, but self.instance has an Entry for the 19th of September. No matter on what day I try add an Entry, it's always today's date. That makes no sense.